# Is there a std::less/std::greater for the spaceship operator?

Tags: c++, c++20, comparison-operators, spaceship-operator

All the basic comparisons (`<`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`, `>=`, `>`) have an associated function object (`std::less`, `std::less_equal`, `std::equal_to`, `std::not_equal_to`, `std::greater_equal`, `std::greater`).

Does the spaceship operator `<=>` have a similar function object?
If not, why was it not added to the standard library?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`std::compare_three_way`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/compare_three_way) is the function object for three-way comparison (aka. spaceship operator).

Comment: Hmm seems some links are missing on cppreference to make this easily findable without already knowing its name.

Comment: @rubenvb cppref is a collaborative effort. You can [edit](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/utility/compare/compare_three_way&action=edit) it

Comment: @rubenvb it [does now](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional)